# HTML Style different from one Platform to another

Tags: android, html, css, angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and am need to get my styles to be consistent as possible between platforms.

I have developed the following Login Page, and this is what it looks like in a **web browser**:

[image]

When I deploy it to an **Android Device**, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the spacing is different, and the icons are absent on the Android Device.

**Question**

How do I get the Android Devices style to match web browser?

My Code:

**html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar id="search-navbar" hideBackButton="false">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-title>login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content>

  <div class="login">
    <div class="login-button">
      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" (click)="loginFacebook()">
      Login with Facebook
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="login-button">
      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google" (click)="loginGoogle()">
      Login with Google
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="login-button">
      <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--email" (click)="loginEmail()">
      Login with Email
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

**css**

```
.login{
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.login-button{
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

body { padding: 2em; }


/* Shared */
.loginBtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 13em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}
.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}


/* Facebook */
.loginBtn--facebook {
  background-color: #4C69BA;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4C69BA, #3B55A0);
  /*font-family: "Helvetica neue", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;*/
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354C8C;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:before {
  border-right: #364e92 1px solid;
  background: url(/assets/icon/icon_facebook.png) 6px 21px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:hover,
.loginBtn--facebook:focus {
  background-color: #5B7BD5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5B7BD5, #4864B1);
}


/* Google */
.loginBtn--google {
  /*font-family: "Roboto", Roboto, arial, sans-serif;*/
  background: #DD4B39;
}
.loginBtn--google:before {
  border-right: #BB3F30 1px solid;
  background: url(/assets/icon/icon_google.png) 6px 21px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--google:hover,
.loginBtn--google:focus {
  background: #E74B37;
}

/* Email */
.loginBtn--email {
  /*font-family: "Roboto", Roboto, arial, sans-serif;*/
  background: #7c7c7c;
}
.loginBtn--email:before {
  border-right: #666666 1px solid;
  background: url(/assets/icon/icon_email.png) -2px 12px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--email:hover,
.loginBtn--email:focus {
  background: #888988;
}
```

Comment: did you try increasing margin to `login-button` class?

Comment: The issue of the icons not showing is because the path is wrong. Change it to `background: url(../assets/icon/icon_facebook.png) 6px 21px no-repeat;` and should work.

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras. That worked